# TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a simple django forum using the example provided here:
http://lightbird.net/dbe/forum1.html

This is the error that I get, when I try to open localhost/forum/

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
Could not parse the remainder: ':index' from 'admin:index'

Error during template rendering

In template /Documents/Projects/dbe/forum/templates/forum/fbase.html, error at line 52

Could not parse the remainder: ':index' from 'admin:index'
42  
43  <body>
44      <div id="sidebar"> {% block sidebar %} {% endblock %} </div>
45      <div id="container">
46          <div id="menu">
47              {% block nav-global %}
48  
49                  <!-- MENU -->
50                  <h3><a href="{% url forum.views.main %}">ForumApp</a></h3>
51  
52                  {% if user.is_staff %} <a href="{% url admin:index %}">Admin</a> {% endif %}
53                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
54                      <a href="{% url forum.views.profile user.pk %}">Edit profile</a> {% endif %}
55  
56                  {% if not user.is_authenticated %}<a href="/accounts/login/?next=/forum/">login</a> | <a
57                      href="/accounts/register/">register</a>{% endif %}
58  
59                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}<a href="/accounts/logout/?next=/forum/">logout</a>
60                      {% endif %}
61  
62              {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the url.
Change

```
"{% url admin:index %}"
```

to

```
"{% url 'admin:index' %}"
```

Comment: @Anish Patil:  This was changed in Django 1.5. Previous versions did not require the quotes for the first parameter, now they do.